# Hide console window

Tags: c#

I'm using a small C# executable to launch a java jar. I want to recover the exit code returned by the jar so i can restart the jar if i need to.
However the c# application keeps showing a black console window and i can't get rid of it, does anyone know how to fix this?
I'm using t he following C# code to start the process

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "jre/bin/java.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-Djava.library.path=bin -jar readermanager.jar";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

p.Start();

p.waitForExit();
return p.ExitCode;
```

The console window only keeps visible when using the waitForExit(); method. Without it (and withoud p.ExitCode) the console windows closes. I also tried setting the StartInfo.WindowStyle to Hidden and Minimized but both don't have any effect on the window.

Comment: Why dont you just use a windows service to do what you are describing?

Comment: Cause i just want an easy clickable executable to start the java application. It's not a windows service. just a desktop application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide Console Window in C# Console Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853629/hide-console-window-in-c-sharp-console-application)

Comment: well, i guess a windows form will do

Comment: A 5 seconds search showed me there's already a question in SO for this

Comment: The only answers i found involved setting the StartInfo as i described in my post. But thanks for the answer, it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Just change the output type of your C# program to be a "Windows Application" instead of a "Console Application". A C# Windows application doesn't really care if you actually display any windows.

Answer (score 1):

From [How to run a C# console application with the console hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836427/how-to-run-a-c-sharp-console-application-with-the-console-hidden)

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo start =
  new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();     
start.FileName = dir + @"\Myprocesstostart.exe";
start.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

But if that does not work, how about this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharpgeneral/thread/ea8b0fd5-a660-46f9-9dcb-d525cc22dcbd

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);


IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Window caption here");

if(hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    //Hide the window
    ShowWindow(hWnd, 0); // 0 = SW_HIDE
}


if(hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
{
   //Show window again
   ShowWindow(hWnd, 1); //1 = SW_SHOWNORMA
}
```

Comment: " I also tried setting the StartInfo.WindowStyle to Hidden and Minimized but both don't have any effect on the window."

Comment: Ah, did not notice that part.