# How to show message box without console or form in background?

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I am new to programming (c#). I have seen in VBScript we can show the message box (standalone). I would like to do the same in C#, just for learning, but the code when executed shows a Console or Form in the background along with a messagebox. Is it possible to only show the messagebox when the program is executed?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("My message");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide Console Window in C# Console Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853629/hide-console-window-in-c-sharp-console-application)

Comment: I just created a new Windows Forms application and replaced the entire code in `Program.cs` and it works as intended - no form window is ever shown, just the messagebox. I even deleted the auto-created `Form1.cs` and the program still builds and runs as expected. Your namespace suggests you created a Console Application - create a new Windows application instead.

Comment: it works, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Console projects, you can hide the console as follows:

- Right click the project in the Solution Explorer
- Select **Properties**
- Go the the **Application** tab in the project properties.
- Change the **Output Type** combo box from "Console Application" to "Windows Application".

Comment: thank you, it did work in Console App. Is the same possible in Windows Forms App?

Comment: The difference to a Windows Forms app are only some added assembly references and the call to `Application.Run(new FormXyz())` in the `Program.cs` file - you'd have to remove that call to not create a main window (but then you can just go with a Console application anyway), or make the Form hide itself after having been created in various ways.