# disabling shell window while running c# program

Tags: c#

I wrote some basic program (from the empty project) which shows window with some buttons, but everytime when I run it visual studio shows me shell black windows, how can I disable this behaviour? thanks in advance

Comment: just create a windows application project or console application project with the New Project Wizard instead of an empty one.

Comment: check here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-console-application

Comment: @Davide Piras: You can post it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

const int SW_HIDE = 0;
const int SW_SHOW = 5;

var handle = GetConsoleWindow();

// Hide
ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);

// Show
ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW);
```

source: [Show/Hide the console window of a C# console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-console-application)