# Display console application window for debugging a DLL

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, class-library

We have a DLL that extends a 3rd party application.  I would like to have this DLL open up a console window when it launches purely for debugging purposes.  I know of the trick to do this with a windows application (change the output type to console application).  Is there any way to do this with a class library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-sharp-console-application ?

Comment: @paddy - That question explains how to show and hide an existing console application using Win32. That's not what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: I know in C you can use the ConsoleWindow API to create and interface with a console window in ordinary Win32 apps.  It looked to me like that post did the same thing.  Your application shouldn't need to be a console application.  A list of console functions is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend using [`System.Diagnostics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.aspx) namespace and using the [`Debug.*`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.aspx)/[`Trace.*`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) methods. Retrieving it is then a matter of using your IDE or (if running in another application) something like [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx).

Comment: Visual Studio is not installed on all the machines, especially production boxes.  That's why attaching is a little bit of a pain.  We'd need to setup remote debugging which is also not possible as us lowly devs have no admin rights.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: You can still use the `Trace` libraries then use the `*.config` to setup log files that you can review.

Comment: Thats what we have now.  It's a little annoying to go into SQL and filter log data as compared to running a console app and seeing live output.