# Is there any way to hide the console by overridding the close button?

Tags: c#, wpf, console

I am making a C# WPF application. I can hide/show the console throught C imported functions (as in [Show/Hide the console window of a C# console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-sharp-console-application)). Is there any way to hide the console by overridding the close button ?

Comment: Do you really need a console application instead of a WPF application?

Comment: Get a handle to the console application and call Kill on it.

Comment: I need the console aside my main WPF app to monitor outputs. I changed my question to be more specific.

Comment: @vanna: Seems to be an odd approach. Why don't you stream the output into a listbox? This should look much better and you can handle the visual appearance as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Console.SetOut and show the output on a window instead: [Console.SetOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.console.setout.aspx)

The best approach however is to use some decent logging mechanisms instead of the Console.