# .net application running silently

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I need to run a .net application c# or preferably VB that will just perform a given task then close itself.

This app will receive arguments from the command line, process calculations, write result text to a file and then end.

Currently I run it as a console app, therefore the user can see the console black window and then the windoiw vanishes.

How can I get rid of the visual element?

Also, once the project is compiled, how can I include it within another solution so that both projects will be published together with clickOnce?

I need two separate projects in the same solution because one of them (the silent one) must run in x86 mode and the other as x64.

Comment: why does it need to be a separate app? cant the other app perform the function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show/Hide the console window of a C# console application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-sharp-console-application)

Comment: The function has been developed as x86 dll by a third party and I don't want my new app to be limited to x86....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the app as a process and set the window style to hidden.

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo start = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();     
start.FileName = dir + @"\silentApp.exe";
start.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This looks fine, but how do you then START the application?

Comment: Found it! process.start(start) LOL

Comment: Check the link above.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using a recent version of Visual Studio, go into your project properties (Application tab) and change the "Output type" dropdown from **Console Application** to **Windows Application**.

Not sure about the click-once requirement, though... haven't been down that road, but it may warrant a separate question.

Comment: Reasonable option if application does not take long time to run (seconds), otherwise I think Windows may get uneasy about lack of window/message processing.