# How to hide console during runtime?

Tags: c#, windows, console-application

Is it possible to hide console window (and run it in background) when I for example type "hide" to the console? Can console app hide itself? If yes, is it possible to later show it somehow again?

By saying "hide" I mean: close window and run as Windows process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show/Hide the console window of a C# console application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-sharp-console-application)

Comment: Here is a duplicate to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5848548/5495213

Comment: Actually, his question is not a duplicate.  He is not just asking if the console can be hidden/revealed.  He is asking if that can be triggered within the console app.

Comment: @Ludwik11, would your requirements allow the toggling of the console window to happen completely outside of the console?  Also, since the console is a Windows process, I assume the most important aspect of your question is the toggling of visibility as long as it is running - true?