# Button click event clicking exe

Tags: c#, winforms

I have simple Windows form With just one button which Calls one url

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("http://myurl.com/");
    Process.Start(sInfo);
}
```

When i click exe then it shows button and then i have to click button to perform action. Is it possible to call button click event automatically on clicking exe.

Comment: Put that method in your `Form Shown` event, or call `button1.PerformClick();`

Comment: Well, why do you need this button in this case at all? Just move this code to the `Main` function.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev can you post it as answer so i can accept

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same with [`Form.Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx) event. Just refactor you code with [extract method](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) to have no duplicated code and call your function in both event handlers:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenUrl();
}

private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenUrl();
}

private void OpenUrl()
{
    ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("http://myurl.com/");
    Process.Start(sInfo);
}
```

Comment: This is the better answer as it splits the functionality into a well named function.

Comment: But this still opens the form which is not i want

Comment: Just click exe and call url thats it

Comment: ok got it.. i just deleted form1 and wrote it in main function

Comment: @Happy you can write console application instead of Windows forms app and [hide it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-sharp-console-application) or just wait while it will closed (immediately after `Main()` function executes).

Answer (score 0):

Simply call:

```
button1_Click(this, null);
```

from anywhere in your code.