# Launching hidden console process, but still with UAC prompt

Tags: c#, .net, console, .net-core, uac

I am attempting to start a hidden console application, but require the application to have elevated privileges.

I have successfully managed to have the UAC prompt appear, however can't get it to appear when I try to start the process hidden.

```
ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
proc.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.FileName = "C:/example.exe";
proc.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.Verb = "runas";
```

This will result in a process starting in the background, except without a prompt appearing (and without elevated priveleges). If I change UseShellExecute to true, then the UAC prompt appears, however the console window is visible too.

Comment: You can hide Console Windows using a Win32 API https://stackoverflow.com/a/3571628/495455

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `WindowStyle` to `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`, as Jexus Manager shows,

https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/blob/be90688abd03780a714dc401054e22fa4afa2be3/Microsoft.Web.Administration/IisExpressServerManager.cs#L41