# How to run this app with hidden or even minimized console?

Tags: c#

```
var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"C:\Program Files\CPUID\CPU-Z\cpuz.exe",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
       for(; ; )
        {
            process.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(20000);
            process.Kill();

        }
```

This program need to be hidden or even minimized?
Can someone explain to me how to upgrade this?

Comment: Have you tried setting the property `ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle` to `ProcessWindowState.Hidden` or `ProcessWindowState.Minimized`?

Comment: You can look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-sharp-console-application#3571628

Comment: @Danitechnik This is Console App btw

Comment: @GamerInTheGame This is Console App btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines to your code

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
```

Comment: Thx, i will test this, but i fixed my problem. Thx anyway:)