# How to hide console in console application using opentk c#?

Tags: c#, opentk

i am using opentk for build a simple 2d, but the problem is that the project is a c# application console, how can i prevent the console application to open on build time? i read using output window application should work, but this is multi platform c# opentk application, any suggestion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-sharp-console-application

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show/Hide the console window of a C# console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-sharp-console-application)

Comment: yes already read that, but Windows Application isnt just for window ? but openTK should  work on linux/mac