# How to stop Reflection.Emit from creating a console window?

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I am generating an executable with `System.Reflection.Emit` (in .NET Framework, so I can save it to disk) and I want the generated exectuable to not have a console window (it should just perform some actions silently in the background).

I tried including a .manifest file, but that had no effect.

Comment: When using [`AssemblyBuilder.SetEntryPoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder.setentrypoint?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-reflection-emit-assemblybuilder-setentrypoint(system-reflection-methodinfo-system-reflection-emit-pefilekinds)), try giving it `PEFileKinds.WindowApplication`. If I understand correctly, this basically just does this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5848548/5133585, but programmatically.

Comment: That does it, thanks! Didn't realize SetEntryPoint had a second overload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you'd do this by [setting the output type of the project to "Windows Application"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5848548/5133585).

In Reflection.Emit, you can do the same thing when calling [`AssemblyBuilder.SetEntryPoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder.setentrypoint?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-reflection-emit-assemblybuilder-setentrypoint(system-reflection-methodinfo-system-reflection-emit-pefilekinds)). You can pass `PEFileKinds.WindowApplication` as the second argument.

```
assemblyBuilder.SetEntryPoint(yourMainMethod, PEFileKinds.WindowApplication);
```