# How to start C# Web API without a Powershell window popping up?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, web-applications

My solution consists of two projects:

- One .NET Core WPF application
- One .NET Framework Web API

I need this setup, because the user needs to be able to interact with old software that requires .NET Framework. By allowing the communication to run via HTTP, I can run two applications (.NET Core and .NET Framework). I am very happy with the way it works, because it allows me to use the newest tools but also communicate with dated software, which is what is required. **The only thing I don't like is that a Powershell window pops up when the Web API is launched. How do I prevent this from happening?**

Reason: it is confusing for the user and I want to prevent the possibility for them to close the API, which in turn would result in a non-operative WPF application.

I have considered a worker service as an alternative and read about it, but I am highly confident that a Web API is what I need, because I have very specific endpoints and object models for the communication.

I Googled a lot, but I have not been able to find an article that describes how to prevent a Powershell window to popup when the Web API is launched. I also read something about 'window style hidden', but how do I integrate this?

Comment: How are you currently packaging and deploying the Web API?

Comment: By using the "FolderProfile" which essentially builds a release version and puts it in the bin\Release\ folder.

Comment: And then....? Normally you'd copy the resulting folder to a location pointed to by an IIS Website

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-sharp-console-application something similar?

Comment: @Jonathan what you posted sounds exactly like what should be my solution actually! I tried it, but it didn't work. It still opens the Powershell showing the logs of my application.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen both appliations are installed using an installer and when opening the WPF application, the API is started using Process.Start(...).

Comment: If you can't change the project type of the API project to "windows application" instead of "console application" have you tried using the WindowStyle of the process.Start...

System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new() {
    FileName = "MyNetAPI.exe",
    WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
};

System.Diagnostics.Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processStartInfo);

Comment: It's unclear what the purpose of this API is. Will it always run on the same machine as the single client (the WPF app), like a sort of proxy? Or will it be hosted on a server for multiple clients to connect to?

Comment: @Rich, in the API properties, I have set the Output type to Windows Application. Also, I have done as you suggested (starting the process with the ProcessWindowStyle set to Hidden. After compiling the installer and installing my application, unfortunately I have still a powershell window popping up. What am I missing? Because I believe what you and Jonathan suggested is exactly what I need.

Comment: @Luke the API will be running locally on the same computer whenever the WPF application is running and will close whenever the WPF application is also closed. I think you could indeed consider it a proxy.