# Visual Studio: how to start up a project without the console window poping up

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide console of Windows Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139637/hide-console-of-windows-application)

so i installed opengl for visual studio by lazyfoo's tutorial.
when i run the project i get 2 menus.
one is the old fashion console window and one is a game window.
i want to start my project without the console window. 
how am i supose to achiev this?
In lazyfoo he tells me to change my linker/SubSystem settings to windows so the console doesn't pop up but when i do this i get this freaky error.
Is there a better way to prevent the console window from poping up?

Comment: what "freaky error" do you get when you chose the Windows subsystem?

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that I hope helps! : [Making my console application invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497652/making-my-console-application-invisible)

Does invisible count as not there?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is answered in the tutorial.

> Under Linker in the System menu, set the subsystem. I recommend
>   setting it to windows if you don't want console output, and console if
>   you do want console output.

Answer (score 1):

I answered it here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6882500/524368

Full quote following:

---

In the project build linker options set

```
/SUBSYSTEM:windows
/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup
```

Or use the following *#pragma* in the source file with the `int main(...)`

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")
```