# How to expand environment variables with substitutions?

Tags: c#, .net, environment-variables, configuration-files, variable-substitution

**Goal**

We are using environment variables like `%logonserver%` and `%userdomain%` in our .NET application's  configuration files, to support configuration freedom to application managers. When parsing the configuration file a call to [Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) resolves the actual value.

**Problem**

However it seems it can not expand environment variables with substitutions like:

- `%logonserver:~2%` (skips the first two characters)
- `%logonserver:\\=%` (replaces the backslashes with an empty string)

When I call `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%logonserver:~2%")` the method just returns the same string: `%logonserver:~2%`, instead of the expanded and substituted variable like a command line call would: `echo %logonserver:~2%`.

**Questions**

1. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?
2. What's an alternative to accomplish this goal in .net?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You make nothing wrong. All the stuff after the colon `:` is a special feature of the command shell that won't be mimic by .Net or the Win32 API (simply check [this code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs#9c2cfdd656c7b3b6)).
2. There are two possibilities:

   - Take the string till the `:`, add a percent sign `%` and give this to `ExpandEnvironmentVariables()`. Then write your own parser to apply the needed actions after the colon `:` to be done on the returned string to mimic the behavior of the console.
   - [Start a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-to-start-a-process-from-c) with a [hidden console window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497652/making-my-console-application-invisible), take its output and input streams and send your environments variables with `echo` commands to it and let the parsing be done by the console.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use something like this (your mileage may very depending on use case, but this works in certain scenarios):

```
private static string ExpandEnvironmentVariablesWithSubstitution(string value)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd",
            Arguments = string.Concat("/c echo ", value),
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        }
    };
    process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => result = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Data) ? result: e.Data;
    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();
    process.CancelOutputRead();
    if (!process.HasExited)
        process.Kill();
    return result;
}
```